# Docker not able to use all of Macbook's CPU cores

Tags: macos, docker, cpu-usage, cpu-cores

I am currently using a Macbook Pro with i7, which has 8 cores. However, I am not able set the CPU cores to more than 1. When I run

```
docker run --cpus=2 "my-image"
```

I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Range of CPUs is from 0.01 to 1.00, as there are only 1 CPUs available.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `docker version`? Do you have docker for mac?(the whale in the taskbar)

Comment: I'm using 17.05.0-ce

Comment: Click the whale and do what @Oliver answered

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to increase the maximum number of CPUs available to containers in the Docker *Server*. In OS X you can find them in Preferences -> Advanced.

Comment: For mac check the other answer

Answer (score 2):

If you use Docker Desktop for Mac, you increase from the UI:
[image]